# Use New Visual Studio Online with Azure DevOps Repo

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to use the new [Visual Studio Online](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/visual-studio-online/) with a private DevOps repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible

Open a new terminal in VS Code online. Create a ssh key with this command

`$ ssh-keygen`

and then, copy the ssh public key whith this other command

`$ cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Copy the output content and create a public ssh key on azure devops

And then you can run a git clone passing the ssh url of the repository